# Triple integral over pyramid

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

The problem is:

Calculate
$$\int_{R}\sin(\pi y^{3}) \ dzdydx$$
Where $R$ is the pyramid having vertices at $B= (0,0,0),D=(0,1,0),A=(1,1,0),E=(1,1,1)$ and $C=(0,1,1)$.

I approached the problem by setting out the points in Geogebra 3D. I then concluded that one can enclose the pyramid with base parallel to the $xz$-plane by $x=0,z=0,z-y=0,x-y=0$ and $y=1$. My question is if it is then correct to say that
$$\int_{R}\sin(\pi y^{3}) \ dzdydx =\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{z} \sin(\pi y^{3})\ dxdzdy+\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{y}\int_{0}^{x} \sin(\pi y^{3})\ dzdxdy$$

Added:

[image: A=(1,1,0),B=(0,0,0),C=(0,1,1),D=(0,1,0),E=(1,1,1)]

Comment: This is really a pyramid?

Comment: @popi "Yes", depending on your definition. It is a square pyramid with the top not being centered. My book, "Calculus-Adams, Essex", calls it a pyramid and I could not think of what else to call it.

Comment: Top is on origin !, it's true?

Comment: @popi Added picture with the points

Comment: Ok, now we can see the pyramid !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would calculate your integral on this way

$$\int_{R}\sin(\pi y^{3}) \ dzdydx=\int_0^1\int_0^y\int_0^y\sin \pi\,y^3\,dz\,dx\,dy=\frac{2}{3\,\pi}$$

Comment: I like your method more! Could you please elaborate on how you chose the limits of integration?

Comment: $z$ varies from $z=0$ to plane $BCE$, that is, $z=y$. After, you must solve the double integral over the projection in $0Z$, that is, triangle with vertices $BDA$. You understand me?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question!